# WhereIn in Query doesn't work for array, Any solution?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have defined `scopeFilter` in Model which has following code

```
public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters){
    $query->when($filters['subjects'] ?? null, function ($query, $data) {
        //Subjects ids will be comma seperated string eg : 127,125
        $subject_array = explode(',', htmlspecialchars_decode($data))
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($subject_array) {
            $query->whereIn('subjects_ids', $subject_array);
        });
    });
    $query->when($filters['topics'] ?? null, function ($query, $data) {
        //topics ids will be comma seperated string eg : 127,125
        $topic_array = explode(',', htmlspecialchars_decode($data))
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($topic_array) {
            $query->whereIn('topics_ids', $topic_array);
        });
    });
    $query->when($filters['search'] ?? null, function ($query, $search) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        });
    });
}
```

Here is how I'm using this in controller

```
$exams = Exams::filter(\Request::only('search', 'subjects','topics'))
            ->orderBy('status', 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->transform(....);
```

If this is passed in url query then the result will be empty. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Basically the are three filter, search works fine but subjects and topics won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Think you miss `return` in scopeFilter

Answer (score 0):

You have not return **$query** in function. [Laravel Local Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes)

```
public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters){
    $query->when($filters['subjects'] ?? null, function ($query, $data) {
        //Subjects ids will be comma seperated string eg : 127,125
        $subject_array = explode(',', htmlspecialchars_decode($data))
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($subject_array) {
            $query->whereIn('subjects_ids', $subject_array);
        });
    });
    $query->when($filters['topics'] ?? null, function ($query, $data) {
        //topics ids will be comma seperated string eg : 127,125
        $topic_array = explode(',', htmlspecialchars_decode($data))
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($topic_array) {
            $query->whereIn('topics_ids', $topic_array);
        });
    });
    $query->when($filters['search'] ?? null, function ($query, $search) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        });
    });
    return $query;
}
```

I hope it helps you :)